# Show that $ f(t) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/t} & x > 0 \\ 0 & x \le 0 \end{cases}$ is in $C^{\infty}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, closed-form

Show that
\begin{equation}
   f(t) =
   \begin{cases}
      e^{-1/t} & x > 0 \\
      0        & x \le 0
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
is in $C^{\infty}$.

---

To show that this is true, I think we have to show that $f^{(k)}$ is continuous for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, where $f^{(k)}$ is the $k$-th derivative of $f$ ($f^{(0)} := f$).

Since the only point where these could be discontinuous is at $x = 0$, I think I need to show that
\begin{equation}
   f^{(k)}(0) = 0
\end{equation}
for all $k$.

I've calculated the first few derivatives in order to see a pattern emerge and create a closed form, but I can't do it. Here are the derivatives.

\begin{align}
f^{(0)} & = e^{-1/t}\\
f^{(1)} & = {\frac {1}{{t}^{2}}{{e}^{-1/t}}}\\
f^{(2)} & = -2\,{\frac {1}{{t}^{3}}{{e}^{-1/t}}}+{\frac {1}{{t}^{4}}{{e}^{-1/t}}}\\
f^{(3)} & = 6\,{\frac {1}{{t}^{4}}{{e}^{-1/t}}}-6\,{\frac {1}{{t}^{5}}{{e}^{-1/t}}}+{\frac {1}{{t}^{6}}{{e}^{-1/t}}}\\
f^{(4)} & = -24\,{\frac {1}{{t}^{5}}{{e}^{-1/t}}}+36\,{\frac {1}{{t}^{6}}{{e}^{-1/t}}}-12\,{\frac {1}{{t}^{7}}{{e}^{-1/t}}}+{\frac {1}{{t}^{8}}{{e}^{-1/t}}}\\
\end{align}

I can see that 
\begin{equation}
   f^{(k)}(t) = f^{(0)}(t) \sum_{i = k+1}^{2k} (-1)^{i}t^{-i} c_i
\end{equation}

where $c_i \stackrel{?}{=} k!$ or something like that. So in fact, I just need to find an expression for $c_i$. Any ideas?

Comment: In fact you do not have to find an expression for $c_i$. Note that $t^n\exp(-1/t)\to 0$ as $t\to 0^+$.

Comment: Is that expression true for all $n$? If so, I think I understand. Thanks!